# Can't train faster rcnn model in my custom dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

So, I am trying to train faster rcnn model for my malaria data. I cloned the repository from https://github.com/kbardool/keras-frcnn.git . I added all the image file and the script itself inside the cloned folder but whenever I try to run the train_frcnn.py script, it shows me syntax error when there is no syntax error anywhere. What could the reason be?

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L01af.png)

Comment: are you trying to run the code in jupyter notebook?

Comment: hi @VedantVasishtha I. am using google colab. I used local jupyter notebook before and it showed the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run any command from jupyter notebook or colab notebook, you should always make it followed by '!' exclaimation symbol.

Try following,

```
 !python train_frcnn.py -o simple -p training_annotation.txt
```